# To Export Data from Spark Dataframe to CSV with User Defined Headers

Tags: pyspark, coalesce

I am reading a Hive table through Spark SQL and storing it in a Spark Dataframe. I am then exporting the data from the Data frame to CSV using coalesce command & it was successful. The only problem is I want to have the CSV Header in some understandable words but it is just the column names.

Is there a way to have my CSV header customized ?

Comment: Rename the df column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.withColumnRenamed('old', 'new')` to rename columns before saving as CSV

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, will check

Comment: This is not working. I still see the old column name

Comment: would you update the question with your code?

Comment: used "dataFrame.toDF(*array-of-new-column-names) * it worked. Thanks for a great start. '*' is mandatory here